# How Do I Configure Wildcard Subdomain Routing in Homestead

Tags: nginx, homestead, laravel-5.3, wildcard-subdomain

Am trying to implement a wildcard subdomain routing in my app. I have done the routing in my routes file.

```
Route::group(['domain' => '{school}.myapp.dev'], function() {
    return $school;
});
```

But am currently stuck on how to configure Homestead to make use of this wildcard subdomains .